# Is UPDATE without a JOIN possible?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a single column (all rows) from one table with a single value from another table. The problem is there is no index fields to join the tables on. Here is an example of the tables/columns in question (without data):

```
Table1: ID, Name, Address, Telephone, PriceList
Table2: PriceList, Description
```

I want to update Table1.Pricelist with the value in Table2.Pricelist

The current data I am testing with has one row in Table2 but it is possible for there to be more. In that case, I would just use the first value returned.

I thought I would post here to get the definitive answer as to whether this is possible.

Comment: Table rows are inherently unordered, so there really isn't a "first one" unless there's also some column like a timestamp or auto-incrementing primary key to `ORDER BY`.  What constitutes your "first" row?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: By the first row I meant whichever row is returned by the query first; a specific record is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET Pricelist = DLookup("PriceList", "Table2");
```

The `DLookup` expression will return a single value from `Table2`.  So when `Table2` contains only one row, it will give you the *"first"* `PriceList` value.  However, with more rows in `Table2`, `DLookup` will still return one value but that may not come from the row which you consider to be the *"first"* row.

It would help to know how to identify which target row contains the `PriceList` value you want to use in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: This works perfectly! This solution will work until the db engine is changed (then it can be fixed with a table redesign). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `DLookup` is handy in situations like this, but is unfortunately Access-only.

Answer (score 2):

```
update table1
set pricelist= (select top(1) table2.pricelist from table2);
```